# Python - Recursive Function Without Return Logic

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

I had trouble understanding why this function returns None:

```
def rem(x, a):
    """
    x: a non-negative integer argument
    a: a positive integer argument

    returns: integer, the remainder when x is divided by a.
    """
    if x == a:
        return 0
    elif x < a:
        return x
    else:
        rem(x-a, a)

rem(7, 5)
```

I then realized that the last line in the function should be:

```
return rem(x-a, a)
```

I am still unsure as to what really happens in the first one. It looks like there are 2 seperate function calls, one returning 2 and the other None... any help?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by this `It looks like there are 2 seperate function calls, one returning 2 and the other None... any help?`

Comment: the first function is simply incorrect, there must be `return` in the last line anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All python function returns `None` if it doesn't terminate by a `return` statement. In your case, you successfully called the recursion but you discarded the result in the `else` part. And after the `if`-block, the default `return None` is implicitly executed.